# Can you add initial data to a volume in Docker that is available on pull?

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm going to use MySQL for integration tests and I'd like to create a pre-baked image with the minimum setup needed to run our tests. This means some custom functions, creation of our database, user setup etc (let's call this image X). What I want to do is that when each integration test round kicks off I'd like to pull and run a new instance of X with the minimal setup.

What complicates things is that I'm using the official mysql Docker image which uses a data volume so that the changes I make when creating X is not stored on `docker commit` and thus are not included when I push the image to the registry.

The workaround, afaik, is to mount the MySQL data volume and take a backup of it that I store somewhere. But in my mind this complicates things quite a lot. Now I need not only pull the mysql image but I also need to download (and maintain) the data volume backup somewhere and apply it to the container before each integration test round.

Is there a better way to solve this? Would a data container help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution may be to create your own mysql image. Take the Dockerfile for the official image and *before* the `VOLUME` instruction, do all your database setup.

With any luck, you should find that your default config is now copied into the volume when it is created.

Another option may be to create an entrypoint script that creates your database etc when it runs.

Comment: I've been thinking about this as well. I don't really like but it may be the simplest thing for us to do.

Comment: @Johan Did this solution work for you? Did you think do something else entirely? I need to do the same and I'm doing some research before I make a decision. It would be great if you could update your post with what you did in the end and if you encountered any problems etc. Thank you

Comment: Yes sort of. What I ended up doing was to modify the official mysql Dockerfile and comment out the VOLUME part. Then I built the image myself and now I achieve what I wanted to do. I don't like this solution but it was the easiest one I found.

Comment: @Johan Thank you for taking the time to answer, this topic was most helpful